# alarma deja de saltar cuando salgo de la aplicacion en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo una alarma (repetitiva cada 1min) definida en una aplicacion en android. Funciona bien cuando la app esta abierta pero una vez le doy al boton de salir (la flecha hacia la derecha), salta bien dos veces mas y ya no vuelve a saltar.¿sabeis por que puede estar sucediendo esto?
esta es la clase alarma que llama a la clase temporizador para crear la alarma:

```
public class Alarma {
    private int ano;
    private int mes;
    private int dia;
    private int hora;
    private int minuto;
    private int segundo;
    private Context contexto;

    public Alarma(Context contexto,int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo) {
        this.ano = ano;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.hora = hora;
        this.minuto = minuto;
        this.segundo = segundo;
        this.contexto=contexto;
        crearAlarma(contexto,ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
    }
    public Calendar crearCalendario(int ano, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundo)
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set (Calendar.YEAR, ano);
        cal.set (Calendar.MONTH, mes);
        cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
        cal.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
        cal.set (Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
        cal.set (Calendar.SECOND, segundo);
        return cal;
    }
    public void crearAlarma(Context contexto,int ano,int mes,int dia,int hora, int minuto,int segundo)
    {
        Intent intentoLanzar = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), Temporizador.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexto, 0, intentoLanzar, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendario= crearCalendario(ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto,segundo);
        //AlarmManager aMan = (AlarmManager)contexto.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        AlarmManager aMan = (AlarmManager)contexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //aMan.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        aMan.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendario.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60, pIntent);
    }

}
```

esta es la clase temporizador:(que es un broadcast receiver que activa una notificacion cuando salta la alarma)

```
public class Temporizador extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context contexto;
    private final static String CHANNEL_ID="NOTIFICACION";
    private final static int NOTIFICACION_ID=0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {

        this.contexto=context;
        createNotificationChannel(contexto);
        createNotification(contexto);
        Toast.makeText(contexto.getApplicationContext(), "Alerta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void createNotificationChannel(Context contexto) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            CharSequence name="Medicacion";
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    private void createNotification(Context contexto) {
        Intent intentoClickNotification = new Intent(contexto, OnClickNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pIntentClickNotification=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexto, 1, intentoClickNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(contexto.getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_medical_services_24);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntentClickNotification);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle("Hora de la pastilla");
        builder.setContentText("No te olvides de tu medicacion");
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setLights(Color.WHITE,500,500);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat= NotificationManagerCompat.from(contexto.getApplicationContext());
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICACION_ID,builder.build());
    }
}
```

y asi es como creo la alarma en el mainactivity:

```
Alarma alarma=new Alarma(this,2022,Calendar.FEBRUARY,27,18,49,00);
```

y este es el trozo de codigo de como declaro el temporizador en el manifest:

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".Temporizador"
        android:process=":remote" />
    <receiver
```

A mi me da la sensacion de que una vez se ha salido de la aplicacion, pasado un cierto tiempo esta se elimina, ya que recibo todavia despues de salir de la aplicacion dos alarmas y ya no mas.
un saludo.

Comment: Recuerda que es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCION:**  Hay que activar la opcion "sin restricciones" en las opciones de ahorro de bateria.

Comment: Estaría bien que indicaras en tu solución cómo se pone esa opción; puedes [edit]. Lo otro: sé que esto es relevante a partir de cierta versión de Android. ¿Podrías indicar en la pregunta qué versión de Android usas para tu app? (o cual es el _target version_)